# How to hide the keyboard in LeanFT while testing android application?

Tags: java, android, testing, automation, leanft

I want to test an android application using LeanFT in java, and I want to know how can I hide the soft keyboard while testing?

Answer (score 1):

How do you close the soft keyboard manually? You do it the same way through LeanFT.

If manually clicking on another control closes the soft keyboard, so will automatically.

You can also describe the button on the android soft keyboard that minimizes the keyboard (if there is such a button).

And if you cannot describe it, you can always click on the coordinates, or using VRI